# Доступ к элементам формы из класса

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.5

Здравствуйте! Помогите разобраться с объявлением класса. Имеются две формы. На `Form1` лежат `comboBox1`, `textBox1`. В `Program.cs` объявляю класс:

```
namespace Test
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
    public class Data
    {
        public string subject;
        public string variant;
        public string Subject(Form1 Form1)
        {
            subject = Form1.comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            return subject;
        }
        public string Variant(Form1 Form1)
        {
            variant = Form1.textBox1.Text;
            return variant;
        }
    }
}
```

Далее пытаюсь в `Form2` обратиться к полям класса `Data.subject` и `Data.variant`, но они почему-то имеют значение `null`.

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        // Внешние переменные:
        System.IO.StreamReader Reader;
        Data Data = new Data();
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var Charset = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
            // Должен открыться файл, но не открывается из-за пустых значений
            Reader = new System.IO.StreamReader
                (@"\Вопросы\" + Data.subject + @"\Вариант " + Data.variant + ".txt", Charset);
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Comment: А Вы не пробовали для начала какую-нибудь книжку по C# почитать?

Comment: @Cirran, используйте, пожалуйста, кириллицу.

Comment: Вы нарушили все мысли и немыслимые принципы ООП, так как делаете Вы, делать нельзя! Интерфейс и логику в одном классе использовать недопустимо. Классы нужно создавать в отдельных файлах, и в качестве параметров принимать не контролы а значения которые эти контролы содержат.

Answer (score 1):

Без инициализации полей они и будут null выдавать. Попробуйте сделать приватное поле типа Form1 и конструктор Data(Form1 form) что-то типа:

```
 private Form1 _form;
 public Data (Form1 form)
{
  _form=form;
}
```

Ну и в Subject и Variant использовать внутреннюю переменную _form.

Использовать не Data.subject, а Data.Subject, и не Data.variant, а Data.Variant.

Как-то так, если быстро....